# What is the time complexity of this recursive function that checks for a permutation?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o

What is the time complexity for the below function? How does it change in relation to length / with the string checking against? I noticed that with length 6, the function executes fast. Once I increase the string to "abcdefg" and length to 7, it starts to slow down. Is the relationship exponential for each additional character you add?

```
    public static boolean permutate(String str, int length)
    {
        if (length < 0)
            return false;

        if (str.equals("abcdef"))
            return true;
       

        for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        {
            if(permutate(str + c, length - 1))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Imagine, you have only 2 symbols in your alphabet rather than 26, then adding a new position will double the possible permutations :) So in this case it 26es them...

Comment: since you try every permutation until the result is being matched it can easily be expressed as: O(n^m) while n is 26 for 26 characters to be tested and m is the amount of letters to be checked. So in your case it would be either 26^6 or 26^7 which is:
308915776 and 8031810176. Stack size will be exceeded quite quickly!

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama Stack size isn't a concern here, since the recursion is bigger in breadth than in depth - while it has an incredibly large number of total runs, only seven of those runs will ever be in the same stack at once, so a stack overflow is quite unlikely.

Comment: What have *YOU* tried so far? For a first idea you can meter the time of different lengths and plot them.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy oh you're right, didn't notice!

Comment: Not sure why this question is being downvoted. What is wrong with and how can I improve it?

Comment: @user3587180 Nothing wrong with it, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like efficiency `O(26^length)`, so, horrendous.

The various top-level `if` statements in the function are constant time, so we don't need to worry about them, But the `for` loop will execute 26 times per call, and it will call itself again each of those times, down to a depth of `length`. Therefore, total runtime is on the order of `26` to the power of `length`. As a complexity class, this can be reduced to `O(x^n)`, or 'exponential'.

You haven't mentioned in your question what this function is supposed to achieve (what it looks like is an extremely inefficient way to do `"abcdef".startsWith(str)`), so I can't really help with optimization.